# gnuplot: errorbars with pointtype variable

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot data with error bars and variable point type. I know, I could do it with two commands:

```
array data = [7, 2, 5, 6]
pl [0.7:4.3] data us 1:2:(0.8) w e pt -1, "" us 1:2:(7-($1==3)) pt var lc 1
```

[image]

I would expect that something like `pl [0.7:4.3] data us 1:2:(0.8):(6) w e pt var` would work, but it doesn't. It seems gnuplot interprets it as `4 columns:  x  y  xlow  xhigh`.
It does not happen with variable linecolor (`lc var`).

So can I plot variable pointtype with one command instead of two?
Drawbacks of two commands: more typing, more difficult to read and maintain, two legend entries (could be hidden with `t ""`, but then it can't be toggled with mouse click).

Comment: Which gnuplot version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `with yerrobars` instead of `with errorlines` it seem to work for gnuplot 5.4.4 and 5.4.5, however, not for gnuplot<=5.4.0 and not for the gnuplot5.5.0 binary which I have. Pretty strange...

**Script:** (seems to work only for gnuplot 5.4.4 and 5.4.5)

```
### yerrorbars with variable pointtype
reset session

array data = [7, 2, 5, 6]

plot [0.7:4.3] data u 1:2:($2-0.8):($2+0.8):(7-($1==3)) w yerrorbars \
               pt var ps 3 lw 2 lc "red"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I have 5.4.3, thus not working. Thx for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Known bug.  Fixed recently, not yet in distributed release.  Description below is from the commit log.

> ```
> fix variable pointtype, pointsize in plot styles yerrorlines and yerrorbars
>
> Despite what the documentation said, these two plot styles did not
> correctly track variable point properties, with the exception of
>     using x:y:ylow:yhigh:(varprop) with yerrorbars
> and even there the variable pointsize was lost unless pointintervalbox
> was set to 0.
>
> Now both plot styles work for either x:y:ydelta or x:y:ylow:yhigh
> and either or both of pointstyle variable and pointtype variable.
>
> It remains a limitation that "pt variable" cannot load character
> point types.  This is due to field overloading in struct coordinate.
> ```